# Insert from stringstream with implict conversion

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, stringstream

I am reading whitespace-delimited single precision values in scientific notation from an ASCII file.  There are multiple values per line.  I populate a vector via a streamstream; the primitive type of the vector may differ from the type of the data:

```
// Illustrates typical string from file
std::string string_with_floats("-2.750000e+001 2.750000e+001 3.450000e+001");

// Template parameter is the desired return type
vector<int> data = ReadValues<int>(string_with_floats);

template <class T>
vector<T>& ReadValues(std::string& string_with_data)
{
    std::stringstream ss(string_with_data);
    std::vector<T> values;
    T val;
    while(stream >> val)
    {
        values.push_back(val);
    }
    return values;
}
```

The example above results in the vector being populated with just the first value, truncated to -2, presumably because the loop terminates as soon as a non-numeric character is encountered. It works as expected when the incoming string contains int values, even when the template parameter is float.

Is there a way to configure a stringstream to perform an implicit conversion and round to the nearest integer, or do I need to insert into the original primitive type first (float) and perform an explicit cast to T?  Ideally, I would like to not have to tell ReadValues about the type of the data in string_with_data - it will always be one of double, float, int, short, or long, and the requested type can also be any of these types.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the type of the data in string_with_data, it would be simpler: just read one single value of that type and then cast it to the required type before pushing it into the vector:

```
template <class T>
vector<T>& ReadValues(std::string& string_with_data)
{
    std::stringstream ss(string_with_data);
    std::vector<T> values;
    float val; // use original type not required one
    while(stream >> val)
    {
        values.push_back((T) val);
    }
    return values;
}
```

If you do not know the original type, it will a little harder, because there is not single type in C++ nor in standard library that is big enough to accept all other types. So you will have to read each data as a string and then decode it into the required type with an auxilliary stringstream:

```
template <class T>
std::vector<T> ReadValues(std::string& string_with_data)
{
    std::stringstream ss(string_with_data);
    std::vector<T> values;
    std::string str;
    T val;
    while(ss >> str)         // first store the value into a string whatever it is
    {
        std::stringstream(str) >> val;   // then read it as the required type
        values.push_back(val);
    }
    return values;
}
```

That way you can be sure that:

- you have not left the trailing part of a float in the stream when reading an int
- you use the maximum precision allowed by the required type when reading the original string

NOTE : I assume that you accept the default conversions...

Comment: Thanks - I took the first approach you suggest in the end, specifying the type going from as a template parameter. I replaced the C-style cast with static_cast<T>(val).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't extracting the data directly from your file as floats, instead of getting first lines, then floats, then integers?

```
double f;
std::vector<int> out;
std::ifstream file("numbers.txt");

file >> std::scientific;

while (file >> f)
    out.push_back(out);
```

Or if you want to do it more iterator-friendly:

```
std::vector<int> out;
std::ifstream file("numbers.txt");

file >> std::scientific;

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<double>(file), 
          std::istream_iterator<double>(),
          std::back_inserter(out)));
```

If, as @SergeBallesta says, you want to make a generic function where you don't know the "original" type, only the target type, in a iterator-like fashion:

```
template <class T>
std::vector<T> ReadValues(std::string& string_with_data)
{
  std::istringstream ss(string_with_data);
  std::vector<T> values;

  using iss_it = std::istream_iterator<std::string>;

  std::transform(iss_it(string_with_data), iss_it(), std::back_inserter(values),
                 [](const std::string& x) { return boost::lexical_cast<T>(x) });

  return values;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've effectively gone for the first option you suggest, albeit in a template method. By the way, I've run into "bad allocation" errors in the past when using istream_iterator with large files, even using a 64-bit build with plenty of available RAM.